# How to get all available SSID names in python without "SSID:"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wifi

Ok so my code is

```
results = subprocess.check_output(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "network"])
results = results.decode("ascii") # needed in python 3
results = results.replace("\r","")
ls = results.split("\n")
ls = ls[4:]
ssids = []
x = 0
while x < len(ls):
    if x % 5 == 0:
        ssids.append(ls[x])
    x += 1
print(ssids)
```

How could I get the output of the variable "ssids" without it saying "SSID (number of SSID) : " before each item?

Comment: `print(ssids.split(":")[1])` Can you include example output? Can you add some example output? What's in the `ssids` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running this locally using Windows yielded a `results` list containing the following example elements:

`['SSID 1 : WYZE_D73596CE021C547F', 'SSID 2 : FiOS-ZLGT4-5G', ...]`

Consequently, if you wanted to modify the list of SSIDs, you could do the following:

`ssids = [ssid.split(':',1)[-1].strip() for ssid in ssids]`

This is a list comprehension which iterates over the existing SSIDs, splits once on a colon and takes the last element, and strips the resulting string (i.e. removes whitespace on either end), and will assign the new list to ssids:

`['WYZE_D73596CE021C547F', 'FiOS-ZLGT4-5G', ...]`

Alternatively, you could iterate over the existing list and print each element if you did not want to modify SSIDs:

```
for ssid in ssids:
    print(f'{ssid.split(":")[-1].strip()}')
```